# getting process handle name

Tags: c++, handle, widechar

I am trying to get the names of a processes handle. I iterate trough a list of all handles and try to get the name like this:

```
void SystemHandle::GetHandleName()
{
    HANDLE hFake;
    char* objectName = NULL;

    if (NT_SUCCESS(DuplicateHandle(this->process, this->GetNativeHandle(), GetCurrentProcess(), &hFake, 0, FALSE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS)))
    {
        POBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION typeInfo = (POBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION)new BYTE[0x1000];
        PUNICODE_STRING nameInfo = (PUNICODE_STRING)new BYTE[0x1000];
        DWORD read;

        NTSTATUS status = NtQueryObject(hFake, ObjectTypeInformation, typeInfo, 0x1000, &read);

        std::cout << "NtQueryObject: " << status << ", Success: " << NT_SUCCESS(status) << "\n";

        objectName = new char[nameInfo->Length];
        if (NT_SUCCESS(status) && nameInfo->Length > 0)
        {
            std::cout << "nameInfo length: " << nameInfo->Length << "\n";
            std::cout << "objectName size: " << sizeof(objectName) << "\n";
            std::cout << "nameInfo buffer: " << sizeof(nameInfo->Buffer) << "\n";

            WideToChar(objectName, nameInfo->Buffer);
            strcpy_s(this->handleName, objectName);
        }

        delete nameInfo;
        delete typeInfo;
    }

    if (hFake) CloseHandle(hFake);
}


void WideToChar(char* Dest, const WCHAR* Source)
{
    int i = 0;

    // get each char from Source and put it in Dest
    while(Source[i] != '\0')
    {
        Dest[i] = (CHAR)Source[i];

        ++i;
    }

    Dest[i] = '\0'; // create the end
}
```

My problem begins at `WideToChar(objectName, nameInfo->Buffer);` when I get to `while(Source[i] != '\0')`.
 I will then get the following **error** :

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00406CE5 in application.
exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xBAADF00D.
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a function more likely to do this correctly, like [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130.aspx) or [wcstombs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d7tc9zw.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allocate memory for the `nameInfo` variable, but do not initialize it. So when you try to use it, `nameInfo->Buffer` contains `0xBAADF00D` - Microsoft magic number for uninitialized heap memory. Then you get access violation. You also should use `WideCharToMultibyte` function for string conversion.

Answer (score 0):

wrap

```
    while(Source[i] != '\0')
    {
        Dest[i] = (CHAR)Source[i];

        ++i;
    }
```

inside an if condition:

```
if(Source != NULL){
}
```